# Focus iframe input does not work in safari 13

Tags: javascript, iframe, safari

I need set focus to iframe input, but it doesn't work in safari 13.

```
el.focus();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't Set Focus in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48547975/cant-set-focus-in-safari)

Comment: no, i need iframe