# GWT: Textbox doesn't show Cursor on Ipad

Tags: ipad, gwt, textbox, focus

I am trying to implement a Textbox that can show fractions with GWT.
Therefor I have an Canvas were I can draw what I want and receive KeyEvents and MouseEvents.

But on Ipad (Safarie and Chrome) the software keyboard does not show, so I created an Composite and combined the Canvas with a Textbox witch gets the focus after each key or mouse Event on the Canvas.

But the softkeyboard does not show up every time so I tried a bit and can see, that the Textbox seems to get the focus (it gets a blue boarder) but does not always show the cursor.

This does not happen on my Notebook.

Is there any difference between being focused and showing the cursor?

I tried:

- Setting the Cursor position
- set the Text of the Textbox.

Any help would be appreciated,
Christoph

```
    public void setFocus(boolean b) {
    //  if (hasFocus) {
        Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {
            public void execute () {
                t.setFocus(b);
            }
           });
        Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {
            public void execute () {
                box.setFocus(true);
                box.setText("x");
                box.setCursorPos(0);
//              box.setVisible(false);
//              box.setVisible(true);
            }
           });

  //        t.setFocus(b);
//      box.setFocus(b);

//      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The iOS browsers don't allow the focus to be set programmatically unless directly in response to a user interaction (i.e. a touch). I believe the reason is to prevent websites bringing up the virtual keyboard for no reason.

The downside is that it clobbers `setFocus()` for websites that want to use it for legitimate reasons. You can't call `setFocus()` in a *deferred* command because that doesn't count as a *direct* response to the user interaction.

(To be more precise, you *can* call `setFocus()` in a deferred command, but it won't have the desired effect as you found out.)

Comment: So I have a chance if I remove the Scheduler? I tried this before but didn't work most of the time. What I don't understand is why does it work sometimes?

Comment: Hmm, possibly what I said was not quite right and all it requires is an interaction on the page first. So if you've interacted already then it will allow subsequent interactions. I haven't tested this theory yet. Let me know if you test it.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48547975/cant-set-focus-in-safari https://medium.com/@brunn/autofocus-in-ios-safari-458215514a5f

Comment: Ok, I tried it and it is working now. Thanks for that.

Comment: Only if I use a PushButton instead of a normal Button it is not working. Has anyone a idea how I can fix that? Or is there a Unicode character for an empty fraction? You can see what I mean here: mathetopia.ddns.net